# Qt5 program unable to connect to mySql on win7 64bit

Tags: mysql, qt, windows-7-x64

I am taking over a project done under QT5 by someone else. The purpose of this program is to connect to a mySql server (5.5) running locally (on the same machine) and perform operations. It does that by connecting to the ip Address of the machine it is installed on.

One major bug of this program is that, when it is running on a 32bit platform e.g. win7 32 bit, it connects to the mySql database just fine. But when it is running on a 64bit win7 and the mySql database became a 64bit one too, it consistently fail to connect.

We setup several machines running win 7 64 bit OS to make sure that it wasn't anything accidental and sure enough it wasn't, except one of these machines happens to be my work computer and strange enough the program connects just fine. In other words, the program is connecting to the 64bit build of mySql 5.5 server correctly on a win 7 64 bit platform, something it failed consistently on all other machines.

We also noticed that the connection will not take place properly if we run the program and the mySql server on a freshly installed win7 64 bit OS.

Based on that I suspected that it it is because of all the software that I installed on my machine. But so far installing a copy of Qt5 development suit on a freshly configured machine did not solve that problem, which was quite surprising because it is quite reasonable to assume the Qt5 brings with itself files needed to perform certain operation correctly.

Can anyone please shed some light on how to proceed next? I'm quite helpless here and I don't even know the general direction to move on next.

Comment: did you connect with the program from your work computer to MySQL on your work computer? Maybe the MySQL instances are not accepting LAN connections?

Comment: Everything is the same. Clearly for testing purposes we need all these machines to have the same scheme.